# How to provide path in jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins

I have installed `Jenkins` through the `wars` file but now I have two `JDK15` and `JDK8` in the system...Can you please tell me how to run `Jenkins` with `JDK8` as it is automatically taking `JDK15`.

Comment: Which OS Windows/Linux/Mac?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting up a Jenkins file where you can specify the java version for each job. You can find more information on https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/

Answer (score 0):

you can try to switch Java version using this :

`sudo  update-java-alternatives --set [JDK/JRE name e.g. java-8-oracle]`

You can find more information here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/121654/how-to-set-default-java-version